# Java variable doesn't increment, stays at 0

Tags: java, variables, object, methods

I have a sorting method and I want to count moves the method does, but the variable which should count doesn't count anything, I just get 0 when I read it.

```
//En variabel för att man ska lagra info i den 
    //Tillfällig lagring. 
    int temp;
    int forflyttningarBubble = 0;
    int jamForElse = 0;

    //Loopar, loopen är inte mer än storleken på arrayen
    for(int i=0;i<allatal.length-1;i++ )
    {
       //En till loop
       for(int j=i+1;j<allatal.length;j++)
        { 
           //Om talet peckaren pekar på större än det andra
           //talet så ska programmet
           jamForElse++;
           if (allatal[i] > allatal[j])
           {
               forflyttningarBubble++;
               forflyttningarBubble++;
               forflyttningarBubble++;
               //Lagrar värdet array "i" i temp 
               temp = allatal[i];
               //Överför "j" till "i"
               allatal[i] = allatal[j];
               //temp värdet överförs till "i"
               allatal[j] = temp;
               forflyttningarBubble++;
            }
         }
    }
    statistik BubbleData = new statistik(jamForElse, forflyttningarBubble, allatal);
    return BubbleData;'
```

here is the object i use

```
public class statistik {
    public int jamForElse;
    public int byten;
    public int[] allatal;

    public statistik(int jamForElse, int byten, int[] allatal) {
        this.byten = byten;
        this.allatal = allatal;
        this.jamForElse = jamForElse;
    }
}
```

When i try to write the value into a file i get "0"

```
//Starttid
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Anropar metoden
        statistik bubble = bubbleSort(allatal);         
        //sluttiden
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        //för att få ett svar på tiden
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        double seconds1 = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;

        //Gör en loop som är lika lång som arrayen
        for(int k=0;k<bubble.allatal.length-1;k++){
            //Lagrar informationen i filen 
            out.println(bubble.allatal[k]);
        }
        //Lagrar tiden också i filen
        out.println("BubbleSort (Nano): " + duration);
        out.println("Antal Sekunder: " + seconds1);
        out.println("Förflyttningar: " + bubble.byten);
        out.println("Jämförelser: " + bubble.jamForElse + "\n\n");
        System.out.print(bubble.byten); // i get "0"
```

Comment: Don't use Swedish variable names. Try to use English everywhere (except in Strings) in the code, even comments. It looks really ugly. And it will be much harder to get any kind of help here on SO.

Comment: Which variable doesn't change value? `forflyttningarBubble`? Where do you test it?

Comment: Se the quaition again, i added more info. Thanks @maksimov

Comment: @maba as you see im beginer in java, but thanks for the tips!

Comment: The variable `whi sholud count`? I have no idea how to interpret that.

Comment: im mean 'forflyttningarBubble' should'nt be only 0, it should be more then that cause i use 'forflyttningarBubble++;'. @Keppil

Comment: are you sure you don't pass an empty array or already sorted array by accident?

Comment: @Heuster yes im pretty sure, because 'jamForElse' gives back this value '327641601' it only 'forflyttningarBubble' who gives back '0'

Comment: @Gunitzo but `jamForElse` is incremented *before* the `if`

Comment: @Heuster thank you man i love you. The file i tried to sort, was already sorted :( awkward

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies within the code to

```
 bubbleSort(allatal);
```

which has a number of flaws in it.  Basically, there is little handling of cases which fall near the edges.  An array of zero elements will never fall into the inner loop, and also never update the `byten` field.  The same will happen with an array of one element.

Have you verified your input to assure that you have enough elements to sort?  Small inputs (arrays of size zero or one) will pass through this as "already sorted", which they are; but, they will not require any actual manipulation.